# Возникла синтаксическая ошибка, но какая понять не могу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Белочка разгрызает кучу орешков, которая равна факториалу числа N, и находит в них изумруды. Количество изумрудов получается равным первой цифре факториала.

Функция

int squirrel(int N)

получает параметром целое неотрицательное число N, и возвращает первую цифру факториала N!

```
def squirrel(self, N):
    s = 1
    factorial = 1
    emerald = 0
    nf = 0
    if(N == 0 or N == 1):
        emerald = 1
        return emerald
    for i in range(2, N+1):
        factorial *= i
    nf = factorial
    while nf != 0:
        nf = nf//10
        s *= 10
    emerald = int(factorial//(s / 10))
    return (emerald)
```

вроде и тесты сделал

```
import random
class my_work:
  def squirrel(self, N):
    s = 1
    factorial = 1
    emerald = 0
    nf = 0
    if(N == 0 or N == 1):
        emerald = 1
        return emerald
    for i in range(2, N+1):
      factorial *= i
      nf = factorial
    while nf != 0:
      nf = nf//10
      s *= 10
    emerald = int(factorial//(s / 10))
    return (emerald)

class my_test:
  def test1(self):
    test = my_work()
    print(test.squirrel(0))

  def test2(self):
    test = my_work()
    print(test.squirrel(1))

  def test3(self):
    test = my_work()
    for i in range(10):
      y = random.randint(0,10)
      print(test.squirrel(y))

test = my_test()
test.test3()
```

Comment: А ошибка-то какая?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При синтаксической ошибке программа не запускается,а эта работает как-то, несмотря на целочисленное деление на вещественное число.

Лишнее выкинул:

```
def squirrel(N):
    emerald = 1
    for i in range(2, N+1):
        emerald *= i
    while emerald >= 10:
        emerald //= 10
    return emerald
```

Comment: А вместо цикла `str(emerald)[0]`?

Comment: `str(reduce(mul, range(2, N + 1)))[0]`

Comment: @gil9red А зачем, если str внутри примерно то же делает,да ещё место под строку выделяет? Или из тех соображений, что встроенная функция быстрее сработает, чем свой код?

Comment: Точнее while emerald > 9: а то в ответе у вас может 10 выдать.

Comment: @coder675 Точно, спасибо

Comment: ``str(emerald)[0]`` понятнее и нагляднее, чем цикл. С циклом надо еще напрячься и подумать, а тут сразу видно, что делается.

Comment: @Эникейщик  Про напрячьcя и подумать - это хорошо :=)

Comment: Это если решать задачки про белочку и изумруды, то хорошо (да и то не факт). А если на производстве заставлять своим кодом всех напрягаться и думать, то этому быстро разучат. Да и Дзен питона никто не отменял :)